# Using Minipage to get this result - Text wrapped box in a paragraph

Tags: minipage, wrap

Can `minipage` be used to get the following result (To highlight the main idea of a paragraph when you do not want to create a separate section).

[image: problem]

I'm really new to LaTeX. Could anyone please suggest an outline for the code?

Answer (score 6):

Please see the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{wrapfig} % <======================== wrap text around figure
\usepackage{blindtext} % <========================= to create dummy text


\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{5cm} % <==========================================
  This is a special part! This is a special part! This is a special part!
\end{wrapfigure}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

and its result:

[image: result]

Please read the documentation of `wrapfig` with typing on your console/terminal: `texdoc wrapfig`!

But please be warned: do not use it together with `itemize` etc.!

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I will read and understand wrapfig. Thanks again